# Is it possible for $BAB = A$ if $0 \prec B \prec I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A, B$ are real, symmetric, square matrices with $A$ nonzero and positive semidefinite and $0 \prec B \prec I$ (in [Loewner ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner_order)). I am wondering whether it is possible that $BAB = A$? Intuitively I feel it is impossible but could not figure out a proof.

I just realized we may argue like this:
\begin{align*}
{\bf tr}(BAB) = {\bf tr}(AB^2) \le \lambda_{\max}(B^2) {\bf tr}(A) < {\bf tr}(A).
\end{align*}
This is a contradiction.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "$0\prec B \prec I$"?

Comment: I mean in the Loewner ordering. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner_order

Comment: The OP might mean that $B$ is nonzero and $I-B$ is positive semidefinite and nonzero.

Comment: @Mindlack: Yes, exactly as you explained.

Comment: @MyCindy2012 Write it in an answer (with maybe a little more detail than that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. If $0\prec B\prec I$, then $\|B\|_2<1$ and hence $\|BAB\|_2\le\|B\|_2\|A\|_2\|B\|_2<\|A\|_2$ when $\|A\|_2\ne0$.

Answer (score 0):

What about
$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=B$?
Then $BAB=A$.

$A$ and $B$ are both symmetric, positive semidefinite, nonzero and $I-B = \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ is also positive semidefinite and nonzero.

For your proof, $\lambda_{\mathrm{max}}=1$ in this case, so the last inequality is not sharp.

Comment: I just realized that the Loewner ordering might mean that $I-B$ is positive definite, not semidefinite, in contrast to Mindlack's comment. In this case, my example would not work.